# Problem on a parabolic girder of a railway bridge.

Tags: geometry

The girder of a railway bridge is a parabola with its vertex at the **highest point, 10 m above the ends**.The span is **100 m**, find the height at **20 m** from the midpoint.

I tried to draw a rough sketch but still i am unable to solve the sum.

Please help.

**Thank you**

Comment: Care to share with us what sum you aim to "solve"?  To be more helpful, please tell us what you know about parabolas.  "Nothing" is a response that will return exactly that.

Comment: Repeating your original question in bold - presumably, we are hard of hearing - will not help us help you.  You did not answer my simple question: what do you know about a parabola?  Writing an equation helps.

Comment: (y-m)^2=4a(x-n) is an equation of a parabola(parallel to or on the X-axis),with coordinates of its vertex at (m,n) & coordinates of focus (a+m,n).The length of its latus rectum is 4a.The x & y's interchange for parabola parallel to (or on the) y-axis,with change in focus (m,a+n)

Comment: OK, good.  Now, what information do you have?  And, from here, you may describe what exactly is the problem.